# FullCalendar not appearing - Laravel

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, laravel-8, fullcalendar-3

Here is my FullCalendar component, I've tried placing the scripts on the parent component and the index component and the problem still persists.

```
<div class="container mt-5 font-semibold">
        <div id='full_calendar_events'></div>
</div>

{{-- Scripts 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#full_calendar_events').fullCalendar({
})
--}}
```

[Here's where I've included it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mECo6.png)

[and here's where it should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/499yx.png)

Answer (score 1):

That `<script>` block at the bottom seems incomplete. Try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#full_calendar_events').fullCalendar({
        });
    });
</script>
```

Otherwise, are there any errors in the console you can share with us please?